# How to convert date to timestamp in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a script to check one of my log files to check its last updated time. If it's greater than 90 minutes, I need to get alerted. But now I am stuck in timestamp conversion.

I have the below line in my code, but it's not working. It's throwing an error like **./monitor_log.sh: line 13: Aug: command not found**.

```
modifeidTimestamp=$(date --date="`$lastModified`" +"%s");
```

The command below is working fine, but I have to use a variable. Can anyone help?

```
 date --date='Aug 25 06:07:30' +"%s"
```

Comment: The backquotes tell your shell to run `$lastModified` as a shell command.

Comment: Thank you @ams. I got it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
lastModified='Aug 25 06:07:30'
modifeidTimestamp=$(date --date="$lastModified" +"%s")

echo "$modifeidTimestamp"
1440497250
```

No need to use reverse tick around `lastModified` variable. Use wrap it in double quotes.